# Tomcat / Spring integration returning 404

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I'm having a similar issue to [HTTP Status 404 on Spring 3.1 MVC app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260777/http-status-404-on-spring-3-1-mvc-app)

But I have not made the same mistakes as that poster did, yet I'm still getting a 404.

web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
version="2.5">

<display-name>Test</display-name>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
</web-app>
```

I am able to load index.jsp but not an actual controller.

dispatcher-servlet.xml file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

<!-- enable Spring’s component scanning -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test" />

<!-- process the @RequestMapping annotations at the class level -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping" />

<!-- process the @RequestMapping annotations at the method level -->
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter" />

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
<property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
<property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Controller

```
package com.test.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;

@Controller
public class BenchController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/bench", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String welcome(Model model) {
  return "yo";
}
```

}

I am able to go to localhost:8080/Test/index.jsp but localhost:8080/Test/bench returns a 404.

I am using eclipse, if that helps.

EDIT 1:

This is the logging.properties. I can't find any of the logs apart from out log.

```
handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

.handlers = 1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler

############################################################
# Handler specific properties.
# Describes specific configuration info for Handlers.
############################################################

1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
1catalina.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = catalina.

2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.level = FINE
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.directory = ${catalina.base}/logs
2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler.prefix = localhost.

java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = FINE
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler

# For example, set the com.xyz.foo logger to only log SEVERE
# messages:
#org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.level = FINE
#org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.level = FINE
#org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.level = FINE
#org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.level=FINE
```

Interesting enough, I'm not sure where catalina.base variable is being defined.

EDIT 2:

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
  </properties>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
      <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>            
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <webXml>/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

I don't see log4j in my dependency tree even though it's in my pom file.

EDIT 3:

Here's how I created my project in eclipse:

1. New Maven Project (m2 eclipse plugin)
2. I selected Simple Project
3. Filled out group/artificat id and selected war as my packaging
4. I right clicked on my project in the project folder window and selected Properties
5. I clicked on Project Facets and converted it when prompted
6. I selected "Dynamic Web Module" and clicked ok

Once I had all that done , I started adding the dispatcher, updated the pom with spring, etc.

EDIT 4:

Alright, I'm finally getting somewhere. After commenting out this lines in web.xml:

```
<listener>
  <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

I was able to directly deploy the application through tomcat manager. Now I'm getting

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
```

It seems it's trying to find the dispatcher-servlet.xml under /WEB-INF folder. After looking inside the war file, I cannot locate the file at all. Every time I place the servlet xml in that folder, it seems to be removed. I can put it under any other folder, but for some reason when I do, it still seems to search for the file under /WEB-INF even after updating the web.xml to reference the new location.

EDIT 5:

Here's an update on my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
  version="2.5">

```
  <display-name>Test</display-name>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>WEB-INF/classes/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/classes/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

</web-app>
```

After explicitly adding the location of applicationContext and dispatcher-servlet. catalina.out says:

```
Mapped URL path [/bench] onto handler 'benchController'
Mapped URL path [/bench.*] onto handler 'benchController'
Mapped URL path [/bench/] onto handler 'benchController'
Mapped URL path [/bench] onto handler 'benchController'
Mapped URL path [/bench/*] onto handler 'benchController'
FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 245 ms
```

But when going to localhost:8080/Test/bench - it still returns a 404.
I cannot acess index.jsp when I deploy through tomcat manager, but I can if I deploy through eclipse. No other output by catalina.out.

Log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Feb/2012:14:41:13 -0800] "GET /Test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 182
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Feb/2012:14:41:19 -0800] "GET /Test/ HTTP/1.1" 200 182
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Feb/2012:14:41:24 -0800] "GET /Test/bench HTTP/1.1" 404 1012
```

SOLUTION:

I followed the instructions provided below and inside the project folder, from the command line I ran mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0 so that eclipse can import the project correctly. I'm working on figuring out how to do this all through eclipse to avoid having to manually do this every time.

Comment: The only logs I've been able to find is /var/log/tomcat6/localhost.2012-02-18.log but that doesn't contain any data.

Comment: Ok I'm sorry my error log was produced not by tomcat but by log4j. So in catalina.out do you see any messages from Spring? Do you see this: `INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet': initialization started` ?

Comment: do you have `log4j-1.2.xx.jar`, `slf4j-api-1.6.x.jar` and `slf4j-log4j12-1.6.x.jar` in `WEB-INF/lib` ?

Comment: catalina.out doesn't have that. It only shows start up / stop messages. I have yo.jsp under/WebContent/WEB-INF/jsp. (/Webcontent is creatd by eclipse).

Comment: /WebContent/WEB-INF/lib is empty. But I have all my dependencies declared in my pom file. I'll update above. Also, I did have some issues with eclipse and googling around told me to run mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0

Comment: please forget `yo.jsp` - it's not needed - I didn't notice @ResponseBody. `/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib` doesn't matter - you should check the deployed application, do you have an idea where it is being deployed? You should avoid running webapps from Eclipse if you want to learn how it really works IMO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You mentioned you wanted to learn how to make Spring MVC web app from scratch - here's the list of steps to produce a working app with your configuration:

1) create a folder `a`

2) in that folder create a file `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>test</groupId>
<artifactId>test</artifactId>
<name>test</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <warName>test</warName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

3) in folder `a` create sub folders `src/main/java/test` and put file `YoController.java` there:

```
package test;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
public class YoController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/bench", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String welcome(Model model) {
        return "yo";
    }
}
```

4) create subfolders `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` and put two files there, `web.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

and `dispatcher-servlet.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="test" />

</beans>
```

5) create subfolders `src/main/resources` and put `log4j.properties` file there:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
```

6) in command prompt from folder `a` type: `mvn package`

7) copy `target/test.war` to Tomcat's webapps folder

8) start Tomcat and go to URL `localhost:8080/test/bench`

I've just completed all the steps and it worked.
Logging shows Spring messages that will tell you if something is wrong.

Comment: Hi. First of all, thank you for taking the time on providing this tutorial. What I meant by doing it from scratch is that I'm trying to create a maven/spring/dynamic web app through eclipse. The main reason is that I'm able to step through code when I need to debug something. And yes your example works great, but this would become tedious having to do this every time I create a brand new web app.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help setting up your Eclipse :(

Comment: I'm deploying to tomcat manager directly instead through eclipse. I get FAIL - Application at context path /Test-0.1 could not be started. org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Feb 19, 2012 6:57:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/Test-0.1] startup failed due to previous errors. I've read there is an exception happening. But I cannot find it in any logs.

Comment: I commented out <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener> I *think* the exception is ClassNotFound. Hard to say without seeing logs.

Comment: so, where do you have ur dispatcher-servlet.xml? Give that path in <init-param> of <servlet> as below: `<servlet>
 <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 <init-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>/WEB-INF/xx/dispatcher-context.xml</param-value>
 </init-param> 
</servlet>`

Comment: @user1218776 ContextLoaderListener class is located in `spring-web-3.x.x.RELEASE.jar` - if it is in application's `WEB-INF/lib` on the server then there is no problem with that

Comment: @user1218776 I've updated the answer (step 2 and added step 5) to enable logging so that you can see what's going on.

Comment: dispatcher-servlet.xml is under WebContent/WEB-INF/. It's in the same location as web.xml and applicationContext.xml. Interesting enough, when I create the war, the applicationContext and dispatcher-servlet are gone! If I place dispatcher-servlet under src/main/resources, it gets moved into WEB-INF/classes, the same thing for log4j.properties. I updated my question. Please have a look. Thank you.

Comment: Hello. I've figured out the problem. It's eclipse. It's the way it creates the directory structure. I've followed your tutorial and then ran mvn eclipse:eclipse to allow project import. Works like a charm. I'll try to figure out a way to create that structure through eclipse, because it's a bit tedious to do that manually, every time. Thank you for your time and help.