# Resources not found

Tags: spring-mvc, http-status-code-404, tomcat7

I am using Spring MVC within Tomcat and what I thought was a standard configuration.  The web.xml looks like this:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>acme</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/acme-spring.xml
    </param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>acme</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Withing the Spring acme-spring.xml, I have the view-controller tag set to the root path:

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="login.jsp"/
```

and the site resolver tag:

```
<bean id="siteResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

However, when I hit localhost:8080/acme, I would have expected the login.jsp but instead, I receive an Invalid URL error.  I took a look at both [HTTP Status 404 on Spring 3.1 MVC app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260777/http-status-404-on-spring-3-1-mvc-app) and [HTTP Status 404 on Spring 3.1 MVC app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9260777/http-status-404-on-spring-3-1-mvc-app) but there was no joy.

Thoughts on what I have misconfigured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your tag should be like this

```
<mvc:view-controller  path="/" view-name="login"/>
```

because veiwResolver will take care about the prefix and suffix.

Comment: I also tried that.  However, I receive the following error from Tomcat: HTTP 400 - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect ().

Answer (score 0):

if you are  accessing it by using just context path ,
then you should either mention your welcome-file list in your web-xml 
or you should direcly access any welcome or jsp which you want to show on start-up.
1.First add below lines or hit localhost:8080/acme/Login.jsp instead of hitting localhost:8080/acme

```
<welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

2. Add servlet name mapping like :

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>app_name</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

1. Add servlet URL  mapping :

   app_name
       *.do //you can write url pattern as per your requir.

check and let me know if any other exception you are facing..!!